# Float value in SLIM query table comparison

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fit-framework

I am fairly new to Fitnesse. I am using the Subset Query Table. It works fine except when I have to compare a float value. Is there a any way I can compare the values to certain level of accuracy ?

For instance the test should pass when I compare 4.12 to 4.1234. But right now, it looks like it is making a string comparison and it fails. Is there anyway I can override the validation part ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tilde character to mean 'approximately equal to', e.g. ~=4.12

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.ValueComparisons for more details.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a shame.  All I can suggest then is that you do your own rounding in your fixture code.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve approx comparison of Double and Float values, I have override the fixture class as the following:

```
public class ApproxColumnFixture extends ColumnFixture {

    @Override
    public void check(Parse cell, TypeAdapter a) {
        if (a.type == Double.class) {
            super.check(cell, new ApproxDoubleAdapter(a));
        } else if (a.type == Float.class) {
            super.check(cell, new ApproxFloatAdapter(a));
        } else {
            super.check(cell, a);
        }
    }
}
```

The two TypeAdapter class use both relative value **epsilon** and absolute value **precision** for comparison.  The precision is detected from the expected input, so that 23.099 has precision 0.001. They also expect special values, such as "nan" for NaN, and "inf" for +/-Infinitive.  Here is one example:

```
public class ApproxDoubleAdapter extends TypeAdapter {
    public final Double ZERO = new Double(0.0);

    private final double epsilon;
    private int precisions = -1;

    public ApproxDoubleAdapter(final TypeAdapter classDoubleAdapter, double epsilon) {
        this.target = classDoubleAdapter.target;
        this.fixture = classDoubleAdapter.fixture;
        this.field = classDoubleAdapter.field;
        this.method = classDoubleAdapter.method;
        this.type = classDoubleAdapter.type;
        this.isRegex = classDoubleAdapter.isRegex;

        this.epsilon = epsilon;
    }
    public ApproxDoubleAdapter(final TypeAdapter adapt) {
        this(adapt, 0.0001);
    }

    public Object parse(String s) throws Exception {
        if ((s == null) || s.equals("null")) {
            return null;
        }
        if (s.equals("0")) {
            return ZERO;
        }
        if (s.equals("nan")) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        if (s.equals("inf")) {
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        precisions = s.indexOf(".");
        if (precisions >= 0) {
            precisions = s.length() - 1 - precisions;
        }
        return new Double( Double.parseDouble(s) );
    }

    public boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
        if (a == null) {
            return (b == null);
        }
        if (b == null) {
            return (a == null);
        }
        if ((a.getClass() != Double.class) || (b.getClass() != Double.class)) {
            return false;
        }
        double aV = (Double) a;
        double bV = (Double) b;
        if (Double.isNaN(aV)) {
            return Double.isNaN(bV);
        }
        if (Double.isNaN(bV)) {
            return Double.isNaN(aV);
        }
        if (Double.isNaN(aV)) {
            return Double.isNaN(bV);
        }
        if (Double.isInfinite(aV)) {
            return Double.isInfinite(bV);
        }
        if (Double.isInfinite(bV)) {
            return Double.isInfinite(aV);
        }
        final double diff = Math.abs(aV - bV);
        if (diff <= Math.abs(aV + bV) * epsilon) {
            return true;
        }
        if (precisions > 0) {
            return diff <= Math.pow(10, precisions);
        } else if (aV == 0.0) {
            return diff < epsilon;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```